# How to set alarm manager in android M

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I use setAlarmClock but delay from the set time.

Mycode

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    intent.putExtra(AppConstant.REMINDER, note.convertToString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
            note.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(getTargetTime().getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent),pendingIntent);
    }
```

Calendar function

```
 private Calendar getTargetTime() {
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, sDay);
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sHour);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sMinute);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return calSet;
}
```

I test with pure android M. And time delay about 3-5 minutes.

Thankyou and Sorry for bad english

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492770/how-to-make-alarm-manager-work-when-android-6-0-in-doze-mode same question

Comment: Don't work for me , I use setAlarmClock() and Inexact with time that I set.

Comment: did you find any answers?

Comment: No, I download sample from googlesample (link: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DirectBoot) And my device don't work (My device is wiko u feel that use marshmallow). I don't sure about problem of my device but other app about alarmclock can work. It delay about 3 minutes