# Multiple cell phone alarms, which one covers the other. Which alarm is preceded? How it works?

Tags: android, algorithm, mobile, clock, alarm

Lets say i set up two alarms

- **09:00:00 (alarm1)**
- **09:10:00 (alarm2)**

and every alarm can snooze for 10 minutes.

Then alarm1 sounds and i snooze it at 09:00:10 so it must ring again at 09:10:10 BUT at time 09:10:00 already the alarm2 is ringing an i snooze it at 09:10:11.

what will happen to the alarm1? when will the first alarm be replayed?

Comment: also technical information about how android handles the alarms will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the following happened. When it was time for the alarm2 to be activated, the alarm1 actually activated.
1st experiment: I postponed alarm1 and the alarm2 deactivated.
2nd experiment: I turned the alarm1 off and the alarm2 was activate, but it was scheduled to ring in past time.

Comment: Really cool. First of all thank you for investing your time to conduct that experiment.
Actually what you said it is really interesting because i was expecting thing to be done the other way around and i wonder if this is the default android clock or some other app! 
What android version do you use? If it is default it may differs from version to version !!

Comment: I use Android 7.1.1. I also agree that it may differ from version to version

Comment: Nice. Thank you for the feedback!
I will also conduct y own experiment with my 5.0.1 version to collect more results